# Postgres SQL - MAX criteria in WHERE - beginner problem

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-limit

I'm taking beginner postgres online course and below is the question and sample answer. But I'm wondering if I can use **MAX** instead of **ORDER BY  DESC?**

---

**Question**:

What customer has the **highest customer ID number** whose **name starts with an 'E'** and has an **address ID lower than 500**?

The **suggested answer** is :

```
 SELECT first_name,last_name FROM customer
 WHERE first_name LIKE 'E%'
 AND address_id < 500
 ORDER BY customer_id DESC LIMIT 1
```

I tried the code below but it returns to nothing. Did I miss anything else? I tried the same concept for other similar queries and it worked. I just don't understand why this one doesn't work. There should be one row affected.

```
 SELECT first_name, last_name, customer_id FROM customer
 WHERE first_name LIKE 'E%'
 AND address_id < 500
 AND customer_id = (SELECT MAX(customer_id) FROM customer)
```

Thanks in advance!
EDIT 1: I wrote MIN in my attempt. It should be MAX, anyway even if I changed, it still returned to nothing.

EDIT 2: Below I added the detail on the "similar query".

Below code works, it basically returns to all the movie with rating of R or NC-17, length more than 55, where the rental rate is the cheapest(minimum).

```
SELECT title, length, rating, rental_rate FROM film
WHERE rating IN('R','NC-17')
AND length <=55 
AND rental_rate = (SELECT MIN(rental_rate) FROM film)
```

Edit 3:
So I thought well, my code above works, so it should work in solving the new query of finding the MAX customer_id.
This is supposed to be simple. I feel realy itchy to know why my code with MAX doesn't work. Please help me.

Let's say that there are 3 rows of data to analyse, see below.

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
first_name VARCHAR(50),
last_name VARCHAR(50),
address_id INT,
customer_id INT
)

INSERT INTO customer (first_name, last_name,address_id,customer_id )
VALUES 
(Eddie, Longbottom, 501, 100),
(Freddie, Longbottom, 501, 101),
(Ellie, Longbottom, 502,99);
```

The answer should return

```
Eddie Longbottom 501 100.
```

But I just wanted to use MAX rather than ORDER BY customer_id DESC.

Please help..! TYSM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.... It's Solved...

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, customer_id, address_id FROM customer
    WHERE customer_id= (SELECT MAX(customer_id) FROM customer 
                        WHERE first_name LIKE 'E%' AND address_id <500)
```

Edit. My other query with MIN- it worked by chance or specifically because when you get the MIN rental_price there are more than one answer. But it's not the right way.

I'm going to definitely request refund for this course!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

That's clearly not going to work (and we have no idea what a "similar" query is unless you show it).

Imagine just two rows

| customer_id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | Doris |
| 5 | Edith |

Your main query matches only Id 5, your sub query matches only Id 3.

Row 3 and 5 are not the same = no row qualifies. You can't split the filtering criteria across two uncorrelated queries.

You would need

```
select first_name, last_name, customer_id
from customer 
where customer_id = (
  select min(customer_id)
  from customer
  where address_id < 500 and first_name like 'E%'
);
```

However the answer you have is a better solution.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. I corrected tha I put MIN instead of MAX. Anyway, the suggested answer definitely works. But I'm questioning why my answer doesn't work as it works in different queries, where I was able to actually filter criteria across two uncorrelated queries.

Comment: The explanation for your specific example is as above, *possibly* your edit-added query is working more by chance, if perhaps the rows with the `min` rental_rate *happens* to also  have a rating of R \ NC-17 and length <= 55 .... but you can test that, can't you? Did you find *all* expected rows?